# TensorFlow giving error "InvalidArgumentError: Input is empty" when training or validating

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-classification

I am trying to run the Resnet model on custom images (transfer learning).

My directory tree looks like this:

```
|-train
|  |-class1
|  |    |-image1
|  |    |-image2
|  |    |-....
|  |-class2
|       |-image1
|       |-image2
|       |-....
|-val
   |-class1
   |    |-image1
   |    |-image2
   |    |-....
   |-class2
        |-image1
        |-image2
        |-....
```

And I created the tensorflow datasets like this:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory( "train", labels='inferred', label_mode='int', image_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory( "val", labels='inferred', label_mode='int', image_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size)
```

But when I train or test the dataset, after a few images it gives me an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input is empty [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

<Figure size 720x720 with 0 Axes>.
```

The dataset I am using is here - https://github.com/xuequanlu/I-Nema - and I have converted all the `.tif` images to `.jpg`. What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: here is the error log: https://pastecode.io/s/82hk68ar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you have

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory( "train", labels='inferred', label_mode='int', image_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size)
```

"train" should be the full path to the directory with the training images not a string.
for example
train_dir=os.path.join(my_dir, 'train') where my_dir holds the train and val sub directories

```
train_dir=os.path.join(my_dir, 'train')
val_dir=os.path.join(my_dir, 'val')
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory( train_dir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int', image_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory( val_dir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int', image_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size)
```

Also note since you are using label_mode='int' then in model.compile
specify the loss as sparse_categorical_crossentropy